# Generating a random IPv6 ULA subnet?

Tags: f#

Wikipedia [describes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address) the process for generating an IPv6 Unique Local Address subnet.

e.g. `fd12:3456:789a:1::/64`

Is there an existing implementation for generating a random ULA in the .NET standard library or in F#?

---

Related:

- Bash: [How to generate a valid ULA in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48974448/how-to-generate-a-valid-ula-in-bash)
- C#: [How to generate random IPv6 in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403541/how-to-generate-random-ipv6-in-c)
- Java: [Generate random IPv6 multicast address Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804744/generate-random-ipv6-multicast-address-java)
- Python: [Generate random IPv6 address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016918/generate-random-ipv6-address)

Comment: how doesnt the C# answer u refer to work in F#? (forgive me, i havent got a clue what an IPv6 ULA subnet is, I assume the C# question is the same question but in C#?)

Comment: The C# one has no answer.

Comment: There exists project that generates random data https://github.com/StefH/RandomDataGenerator